# Django grid form for 2D array of entries

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have two lists (these are just small examples):

```
Attackers = ['John', 'Mary']
Defenders = ['Steve', 'Bill', 'Dave']
```

My objective is to create a 2D grid form with the appropriate amount of inputs (checkboxes) representing all possible relationships between the two lists.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this at both the model and view level. I've looked into inline formsets and model formsets, but I'm not really sure how to proceed.

EDIT:

```
{% for at in atts %}
    {% for def in defs %}
        <input type="text" name="{{ at }}_{{ def }}" value="{{ at }}_{{ def }}" >
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Create one checkbox for every pair. Put those pairs in the correct order in your form (given that HTML favours a left-to-right, then down layout), and display it appropriately in your template.

Comment: Do you mean just to create the grid manually in the template view? Ideally, I wanted to use some of the form stuff for validation purposes and also maintain some type of filterable relationship between the two lists.

Comment: Doing as I suggest will not prevent you from using form validation or forms: "Put those pairs in the correct order in your form". Django forms are not especially helpful for creating filterable relationships, except for validating the data that is sent back to the server.

Comment: So you are suggesting something like in the edit (possibly rendered by a form)?

Comment: Not really. I am suggesting that you iterate over your form, and you use the template for what it is for - to format the layout of those elements.

Comment: I'm a little confused. How would I create such a form class? I should have specified this earlier, but those lists are just toy examples, the actual lists will be longer so enumerating each field of the form does not seem the best idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21913/discussion-between-ross-b-and-marcin)

Comment: Your form has a collection of its fields called `fields`, which is a dict mapping field name to field object. You will want to populate this programmatically. If you crack open the forms code in django/examine a form object in the shell, you will see (unless my memory is mistaken) that there is also a list or tuple of fields, which controls the order of iteration. You will want to populate this in the right order, as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one checkbox for every pair. Put those pairs in the correct order in your form (given that HTML favours a left-to-right, then down layout), and display it appropriately in your template.

**To create the checkboxes:** Your form has a collection of its fields called fields, which is a dict mapping field name to field object. You will want to populate this programmatically. If you crack open the forms code in django/examine a form object in the shell, you will see (unless my memory is mistaken) that there is also a list or tuple of fields, which controls the order of iteration. You will want to populate this in the right order, as described above.

**To display it**: Iterate over the form in your template. You will want to include some information in the form, or otherwise pass to the template, to described the shape of the grid, so your template code can figure out where to put row boundaries.